# Admob tgkill Crash on Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, admob

We are developed game using Unity & Admob. We got too many crashes. We known that reason is Admob.

When I kill app on focus-out , Game is crashed (not all time. It is hard to reproduce)

Stack Trace :

```
Caused by java.lang.Error: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (?), fault addr --------
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/dreamltexx/dreamlte:7.0/NRD90M/G950FXXU1AQF7:user/release-keys'
Revision: '10'

at libc.tgkill(tgkill:12)
       at libc.pthread_kill(pthread_kill:34)
       at libc.raise(raise:10)
       at libc.__libc_android_abort(__libc_android_abort:34)
       at libc.abort(abort:4)
       at libc.abort(abort:4)
       at libc.abort(abort:4)
       at libc.abort(abort:4)
       at libc.abort(abort:4)
       at libc.abort(abort:4)
       at libc.abort(abort:4)
       at libc.abort(abort:4)
       at libc.abort(abort:4)
```

Tools and SDK versions :

```
Unity 5.5.3f1
Admob 3.4.0
Google Play Services 10.2.0
    play-services-ads-lite-10.2.0
    play-services-base-10.2.0
    play-services-basement-10.2.0
    play-services-gcm-10.2.0
    play-services-iid-10.2.0

Game On Focus : 99% Not Focus , 1% Focus
Operating System : 97% Android 7.x
```

How can we fix it ?